# Rasa - I want same reply for every kind of conversation start

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I have few intents.

But what I want is, at the start of conversation not matter what is being asked I want to always give welcome message.

I tried few things to achieve this   but didn't work.

> - rule: rule-3
>   conversation_start: true
>   steps:
>
>   - intent: product_price
>   - action: utter_greet

For example in my story if at any other places for same intent I want different action.
But for same intent at the start of conversation I want greet message.
But then when I implement above technique it says contradicting rule and story.

Please note - user can start conversation literally by anything (and thus I can't have intent for each and everything) and I always want to greet with welcome message.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this using slots.

For every intent I have these story:

```
stories:

- story: -story-1
  steps:
    - slot_was_set:
      - start_conv: false
    - intent: greet
    -  action: action_greet


- story: -story-2
  steps:
    - slot_was_set:
      - start_conv: false
    - intent: goodbye
    -  action: action_greet


- story: -story-3
  steps:
    - slot_was_set:
      - start_conv: false
    - intent: product_price
    -  action: action_greet
```

Now every real story always starts with this:

```
story: onroad_price greet1
 steps:

slot_was_set:
start_conv: true
intent: onroad_price
action: action_onroad_price_query
intent: assert_yes
action: action_onroad_price_answer


story: onroad_price greet2
 steps:
slot_was_set:
start_conv: true
intent: onroad_price
action: action_onroad_price_query
intent: assert_no
action: utter_more_help
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are searching it too far.
Normally you just set your start intent in the interface that your client is talking to, so that on the moment your client connects it will see the welcome message.
After he can ask any question he wants and hit any intent needed.